# how to open vim in a specific directory

Tags: vim

Right now I have a project that holds the code for the backend and frontend.
Root folder: `Project` then this folder has this following contents.

```
backend/
frontend/
package.json
```

But everytime I open vim in the `Project/backend` directory, it opens my vim on the `Project` directory. Is there a way to make my vim open in `Project/backend`?

I currently have 2 plugin installed. Nerdtree and Vimfugitive

Comment: How do you open vim in the backend directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any configurations to Nerdtree, `vim /path/to/file` should open up Nerdtree on `file` if it is a directory (hijacking Netrw, vim's default file explorer, which would have opened on the directory otherwise). If you're sitting in `Project/backend/`, you should be able to run `vim .` to open the `backend/` directory.

If you're asking how to open Nerdtree rooted at that directory from within vim, you can run `:NERDTree /path/to/dir`, and you'll have opened a Nerdtree rooted at `dir`, which you may now toggle with `:NERDTreeToggle`. Note that when you open a directory with `vim /path/to/dir` from the commandline, you'll have opened the directory file with Nerdtree however the vim window's Nerdtree won't actually be rooted anywhere so using `:NERDTreeToggle` (or `:NERDTree`) will use vim's current working directory, which will by default be the folder you were in when you ran `vim`, and not necessarily `/path/to/dir`.

It might be worthwhile writing a little script in your config to store the initial directory you opened vim in in a variable so that you can have `NERDTree original_dir` bound to a key if you want to be able to easily open Nerdtree on the original directory you opened. Perhaps someone who knows more about Nerdtree might know of an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cd Project/backend
$ vim
```

is the simplest way to start Vim in `Project/backend`.

Once in Vim, you can use:

- `:help :cd` to change the working directory globally,
- `:help :lcd` to change the working directory for the current window,
- `:help :tcd` to change the working directory for the current tab page.

Example:

```
:cd ../frontend
```